# Azure Synapse AI using dedicated SQL server VM

Tags: azure-synapse

Is it possible to add dedicated SQL server VM to azure synapse sql pool for machine learning purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only create a new dedicated sql pool.

Moreover, the official guide is to **use AML service for ML** related experiments - both training and inference. Here is a guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/machine-learning/tutorial-sql-pool-model-scoring-wizard

If you wanna use your dedicated SQL Server VM, it can be used as Integration->Integration runtimes->Self-hosted. But that is for data flows/pipelines so totally different objective (ref: Azure Data Factory).